# How do I make the bot to change a voice channel's name? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

My idea here is to make the bot change a voice channel name depending on the text after the command. For example the command `=changename p` will change the vocal channel name into `" Pepper"`. However, I can't get the bot to do that.

This is the only code that worked to me:

```
client.on('message', message =>
{
    if (message.channel.id === '748181582241857657') 
    {
        if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        const channel = '843111736898617384' 
        //The ID of the vocal channel I want to change name
        const name = message.content.replace('=changename ','')

        if (command === 'changename')
        {
            if (name === 'p')
            message.channel.setName(' Pepper')
        }
    }
});
```

However this change the name of the channel where the message is written and not the one I want. Everything other than that crashed the bot so I don't really know. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the name of `message.channel`, not the one with the ID of `channel`.

You need to get the voice channel first. You can use [`guild.channels.resolve(ID)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=resolve) to resolve the ID to a voice channel object and once it's resolved, use the [`setName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=setName) method to change its name.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'changename') {
    if (!args[0])
      return message.channel.send('You must provide a new channel name');

    const voiceChannelID = '843111736898617384';
    const abbr = {
      a: ' Avocado',
      b: ' Banana',
      c: ' Coconut',
      d: ' Date',
      k: ' Kiwi',
      p: ' Pepper',
    };
    const name = abbr[args[0]];

    if (!name)
      return message.channel.send(`${args[0]} is not a valid channel name`);

    const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.resolve(voiceChannelID);
    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send(
        `Can't find a voice channel with the ID \`${voiceChannelID}\``,
      );

    voiceChannel
      .setName(name)
      .then((newChannel) =>
        message.channel.send(`The channel's new name is ${newChannel.name}`),
      )
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```